# Oracle SQL -- Getting List of Vendors That Do Not Sell Specific Items

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question on my homework that is baffling me.

> List every vendor identification number and vendor name that does not
>   supply ‘power range’ and ‘power screw driver’.

---

So, we have a vendor, vendorcatalog, and inventorydes table.

**Vendor**

vid (vendor ID - primary key)
vendorname
address

**Vendorcatalog**

vid (vendor ID)
itemno (item number)

Both are primary keys.

**Inventorydes**

itemno (primary key)
itemdescription

---

**Current Query**

```
SELECT vid, vendorname 
    FROM  (SELECT vendor.vid, vendor.vendorname 
               FROM inventorydes, vendor, vendorcatalog 
               WHERE inventorydes.itemno = vendorcatalog.itemno 
                   AND vendorcatalog.vid = vendor.vid 
                   AND inventorydes.itemdescription NOT IN ('power range', 'power screw driver'))
```

This shows all of the vendors that do not supply the item, but then it lists each vendor for each item they sell.  What I need just a list of the vendor IDs with the vendor name, not the vendor IDs with the vendor names for each item that is being sold.

So, what I need is a SQL query (being run on an Oracle database) that will get each of the vendor IDs that does not supply the power range and power screw driver.

The end output should be this:

v1 | this vendor's name
v2 | this vendor's name
v3 | this vendor's name

There are only 4 vendors and the 4th vendor is the one that supplies the power range and power screw driver.

Answer (score 1):

untested but this should work:

```
SELECT V.vid, V.vendorname
FROM Vendor V
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
SELECT 1
FROM vendorcatalog VC, inventorydes I
WHERE V.vid=VC.vid AND I.itemno=VC.itemno 
AND I.itemdescription IN ('power range', 'power screw driver')
)
```

Comment: I apologize for the similarity but they are different, honest ha ha. The IN is not negated in my second select, and I make sure that the same vendor is referenced in each select by naming it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
vid, 
vendorname 
FROM 
vendor
WHERE 
 NOT EXISTS
 (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM 
   inventorydes, 
   vendorcatalog 
  WHERE 
   inventorydes.itemno = vendorcatalog.itemno AND 
   vendorcatalog.vid = vendor.vid AND 
   inventorydes.itemdescription IN ('power range', 'power screw driver')
  )
```